# conditionally set propoerty bindings in Angular

Tags: html, angular7

I, im in a little trouble with angular, im just a beginner so maybe this is a stupid question, but i cannot find a good solution.

i have a classic material design tag for paginator

```html
<mat-paginator
        #paginator
        [length]="totalProducts"
        [pageSize]="productsPerPage"
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
        (page)="onChangedPage($event)"
></mat-paginator>
```

i want to put conditionally the properties. 
for example i want to remove [pageSize] or add other in according to page width.

thank you for you help

Comment: What you mean by page width? do you mean the viewport width;

Comment: is just an idea, i want to know if there is a way to put a condition over a single property in properties bindings list, sorry for misunderstanding of the question